# MySQL database password question

Tags: mysql

what should my database password include and not include? I'm using mySQL and PHP

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia actually has [a pretty extensive article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength) on the subject of password strength.  Definitely worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

- Lowercase Letters (a-z)
- Uppercase Letters (A-Z)
- Numbers (0-9)
- Special Characters

Also ensure that you password isnt something silly short like 4 chars. Make it a nice long password, 10+ chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can read guidelines at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.0/en/password-security.html

Answer (score 0):

My personal rule for choosing mysql password are:

- It should be a valid var name.
- It should include upper and lowercase letters.
- Uppercase letters shouldn't necessarily be at the beginning of a word. eg : `woRd`
- It should be longer than 15 chars.
- It should include include numbers.
- It should never reference the name of my project or something about me.

eg:  `fLodHooters_25_lightsOn`